# Создать функцию с двумя аргументами, первый - множитель, второй - длина массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

> Create a function with two arguments that will return an array of the
> first (n) multiples of (x).
>
> Assume both the given number and the number of times to count will be
> positive numbers greater than 0.
>
> Return the results as an array
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> countBy(1,10) === [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
> countBy(2,5) === [2,4,6,8,10]
> ```

В примере указана проблема. Нужна функция, которая будет возвращать массив, от 1 до 10 (в первом случае) единица - множитель, 10 - длина массива. Во втором случае: 2 - множитель, 5 - длина массива. Если, например, указать countBy(3,3), то вернуться должен массив вида [3,6,9]

```
function countBy(x, n) {
  let z = [];
}

return z;
```

```
    function countBy(x, n) {
  
  let z = [];
  let arr = Array(n).fill().map((e, i) => i + 1)
  z = arr.map((el) => el*x)
    return z;

  }
```

Решил самостоятельно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учебное задание начального уровня. Серьёзная проблема заключается в лени.

```js
function countBy(x, n) {
  let z = [];
  for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    z.push(i * x);
  }
  return z;
}

console.log(countBy(1, 10));
console.log(countBy(2, 5));
console.log(countBy(3, 3));
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, вы правы. Проблема заключается не в лени, а в самом начальном уровне подготовки (если это можно вообще назвать подготовкой). В 35 лет изучать JS на работе - довольно сложно. Все говорят "Больше практики!" а где ее взять если не на кодварс? Много умников на дороге встречается, которые только и делают, что демотивируют. Я своего все-равно добьюсь... Кстати решил сам.

Comment: Ах да, мой код работает быстрее.

Comment: Хм, вы смогли ответить на вопрос, который был закрыт. Любопытно...

Comment: @psina, то что сами решили это хорошо. Условия по поводу скорости работы в задаче не было. А вот игры с галочкой пользы Вам не принесут. Удачи.

Comment: @wololo, ну Вы же смогли закрыть вопрос, на который писался ответ ;-)

Comment: Спасибо товарищи.